# Total newbie: Instance variables in ruby?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

Pardon the total newbiew question but why is @game_score always nil?

```
#bowling.rb

class Bowling
  @game_score = 0
    def hit(pins)
        @game_score = @game_score + pins
    end

    def score
        @game_score
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes this the Java way, welcome in Ruby :D

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Let's walk through the code, shall we?

```
#bowling.rb

class Bowling
  @game_score = 0 # (1)
```

At this point (1), we are still inside the *class* `Bowling`. Remember: classes are just objects like any other. So, at this point you are assigning `0` to the instance variable `@game_score` *of the class object `Bowling`*.

```
 def hit(pins)
  @game_score = @game_score + pins # (2)
```

Now (2), we are inside an *instance method* of the `Bowling` class. I.e.: this is a method that is going to belong to an *instance* of `Bowling`. So, now the instance variable `@game_score` belongs to an *instance* of the `Bowling` class, and not to the class itself.

Since *this* instance variable is never initialized to anything, it will evaluate to `nil` (in Ruby, uninitialized variables always evaluate to `nil`), so this evaluates to `@game_score = nil + pins` and since `nil` doesn't have a `#+` method, this will result in a `NoMethodError` exception being raised.

```
 end
 def score
  @game_score # (3)
```

And here (3), we are again inside an *instance method* of the `Bowling` class. This will always evaluate to `nil`, for the reason I outlined above: `@game_score` is never initialized, therefore it evaluates to `nil`.

```
 end
end
```

We can use Ruby's reflection capabilities to take a look at what's going on:

```
p Bowling.instance_variable_get(:@game_score) # => 0
b = Bowling.new
p b.instance_variable_get(:@game_score) # => nil
```

Now let's inject a value into the instance variable:

```
b.instance_variable_set(:@game_score, 1)
p b.score # => 1
b.hit(3)
p b.score # => 4
```

So, we see that everything works as it should, we only need to figure out how to make sure the instance variable gets initialized.

To do that, we need to write an initializer method. Strangely, the initializer method is actually a private *instance method* called `initialize`. (The reason why `initialize` is an instance method and not a class method, is actually quite simple. Ruby splits object creation in two phases: memory allocation and object initialization. Memory allocation is done by a *class* method called `alloc` and object initialization is done by an *instance* method called `initialize`. (Objective-C programmers will recognize this.) The reason why `alloc` is a class method is simply that at this point in the execution there is no instance yet. And the reason that `initialize` is an instance method is that object initialization is obviously per-object. As a convenience, there is a standard factory class method called `new` that calls both `alloc` and `initialize` for you.)

```
class Bowling
 def initialize
  @game_score = 0
 end
end
```

Let's test this:

```
c = Bowling.new
p c.score # => 0
c.hit(2)
p c.score # => 2
```

BTW: just some minor Ruby style tips: indentation is 2 spaces, not 1 tab. And your `hit` method would more idiomatically be `@game_score += pins`.

Answer (score 17):

Because you don't have

```
def initialize
  @game_score = 0
end
```

The assignment in the class definition is not doing what you think it is doing, and when `hit` gets invoked it can't add to `nil`.

If you now ask *what happened to `@game_score`?*, well, always remember *Class is an object* and *Object is a class*.

It's way cool the way Ruby classes have this Zen-like "real" existence. Ruby doesn't precisely have named classes, rather, class names are references to objects of class `Class`. By assigning to `@game_score` outside of an instance method you created a *class instance variable*, an attribute of the class object `Bowling`, which is an instance of class `Class`. These objects are not, in general, very useful. (See Chapter 1, *The Ruby Way*, Hal Fulton.)

Answer (score 9):

`@game_score` defined there is called **class instance variable**,  which is a variable defined for the singleton class object:

```
class << Bowling
  attr_accessor :game_score
end

Bowling.game_score #=> 0
```

This is as you can tell different from the normal **instance variables** defined for instance objects.

Answer (score 0):

@game_score will never get a value of zero here - you need to put it inside initialize, as in

def initialize
  @game_score = 0
end