# Local variables in class definitions / scope

Tags: ruby, scope

I was under the impression that class definitions in Ruby can be reopened:

```
class C
  def x
    puts 'x'
  end
end

class C
  def y
    puts 'y'
  end
end
```

This works as expected and `y` is added to the original class definition.

I'm confused as to why the following code doesn't work as expected:

```
class D
  x = 12
end

class D
  puts x
end
```

This will result in a `NameError` exception. Why is there a new local scope started when a class is reopened? This seems a little bit counterintuitive. Is there any way to continue the previous local scope when a class is extended?

Comment: This is a good question on its own, but is there a reason you want to do this instead of storing an instance variable on the class object itself (i.e. replace `x` with `@x` above)?

Comment: @Phrogz No, there's no reason I'd want to do this in production code. I'm asking this to scratch an intellectual itch rather to solve a real-world problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Local variables are not associated with an *object*, they are associated with a *scope*.**

Local variables are lexically scoped. What you are trying to do is no more valid than:

```
def foo
  x = :hack if false  # Ensure that x is a local variable
  p x if $set         # Won't be called the first time through
  $set = x = 42       # Set the local variable and a global flag
  p :done
end

foo                   #=> :done 

foo                   #=> nil (x does not have the value from before)
                      #=> done
```

In the above it's the same method, on the same object, that's being executed both times. The `self` is unchanged. However, the local variables are cleared out between invocations.

Re-opening the class is like invoking a method again: you are in the same `self` scope, but you are starting a new local context. When you close the `class D` block with `end`, your local variables are discarded (unless they were [closed over](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)).

Answer (score 6):

In ruby, local variables accessible only in scope that they are defined. However, the `class` keywords cause an *entirely new* scope.

```
class D
  # One scope
  x = 12
end

class D
  # Another scope
  puts x
end
```

So, you can't get access to local variable that defined in first `class` section, because when you leave first scope, local variable inside it is destroyed and memory is freed by garbage collection.

This is also true for the `def`, for example.

Comment: Isn't this just restating the question?  Yes, it is a different scope, the OP recognized that.  But why?

Comment: Thanks, I made an addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution would be to make *x* a [class instance variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084490/ruby-class-variables).  Of course, this doesn't answer your scope question.  I believe the reason *x* is not in the [scope](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope) (see *Detecting the Scope of a Ruby Variable*) of the re-opened class is because its scope was never that of class *D* in the first place.  The scope of *x* ended when class *D* closed because *x* is neither an instance variable nor a class variable.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Not true. Try `x=42; class Foo; x=17; p x; end; p x` and notice that you see `17` and then `42`.Opening a class does start a new local context.

Answer (score 0):

A part of the reason of why this behavior makes sense lies with metaprogramming capabilities; you could be using some *temporary* variables to store data that you could use to name a new constant, or to reference a method name:

```
class A
  names, values = get_some_names_and_values()

  names.each_with_index do |name, idx|
    const_set name, value[idx]
  end
end
```

Or maybe, you need to get the eigenclass...

```
class B
  eigenclass = class << self; self; end
  eigenclass.class_eval do
    ...
  end
end
```

It make sense to have a new scope every time you reopen a class, because in Ruby you often write code inside a class definiton that is actual code to be executed and *opening* a class is just a way to get the right value for `self`. You don't want the content of the class to be polluted by these variables, otherwhise you'd use a class instance variable:

```
class C
    @answer = 42
end

class C
  p @answer
end
```