# what is a class variable in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm reading the book Programming Ruby but cannot understand what a class variable @@var is. Can anyone give me some explanation? The book does not talk anything but just mentioned it.

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084490/ruby-class-variables

Comment: Check out [John Nunemaker's blogpost on Class and Instance Variables In Ruby](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) for a very good explanation.

Comment: I'm talking about class variables @@var instead of instant variables @var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class variable is like an instance variable (`@some_var`), but its value is global to the class, and any instances of the class.

An example

```
class Test
  @@test_var = 0
  def show_test
    puts @@test_var
    @@test_var += 1
  end
end

a = Test.new
b = Test.new

a.show_test # prints 0
b.show_test # prints 1
```

Comment: So it's like static variables in other languages such as java?